# Using typestrict get and set on a class, how to set/push a single object into an array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I'm in the process of learning TypeScript. I have a class that is going to manage a set of blog posts. I need to make an array of posts available (with get) and accept a single post object with I then push to the posts class. **but this gives an error**

```
export interface PostInterface {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  content: string;
} 
class Data {
  private _posts: PostInterface[] = [];
  constructor() {
    this._posts = [
      {
        id: 1,
        title:  "first post",
        content:  "first content",
      },
    ];
  }
  public get posts(): PostInterface[]{
    return this._posts
  }
  public set posts(singlePost: PostInterface[]) { // <---- THIS IS THE ISSUE
    this._posts.push(singlePost[0]);
  } 
   
}

export default new Data();
```

It sort of works like that but that's not what I want `singlePost` is not going to be an array but an object and leaving it like `posts(singlePost: PostInterface)` throws an error

Back in my API I'm doing this

```
import Data, {PostInterface} from './data' // the above
const posts: PostInterface[] = request.body
Data.posts = posts
response.json({ data: Data.posts })
```

But when posting to this api I don't want to have to wrap my object into an array for no reason.

Is this really how it should work? can't I `get` a list of posts (`PostInterface[]`) and set a single post object (`PostInterface`)

Comment: Do not export a `new` instance. If you want to have a single object only in your entire application, you wouldn't use a `class`.

Comment: A setter should not accept a different data type than the result type of the getter.

Comment: @Bergi I found that exporting the instance I'm getting the same state all over the place. This is a dummy next.js api thing and so when I use it for all the api methods I'm not getting a different instance every time.

Comment: Having "the same state all over the place" is very much the antipattern that you should avoid.

Comment: @Bergi can you expand on why?

Comment: Because littering global state all over the code makes it unpredictable, untestable, and unmaintainable. You should keep your application state in a single location, in *main.js*, and pass it to the relevant parts of your application via dependency injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply remove the setter and push directly to the `posts` array?

```ts
Data.posts.push(request.body as PostInterface);
```

Otherwise, you could implement an `addPost` method. This is a common practice when you want to prevent collection mutation outside the class

```ts
public get posts(): ReadonlyArray<PostInterface> {
  return this._posts; // return an immutable version
}

public addPost(post: PostInterface): Data {
  this._posts.push(post);
  return this;
}
```

Comment: Or maybe return a `readonly PostInterface[]`, then you don't need to make the copy

Comment: @Bergi cheers, I never touch JS / TS classes so wasn't aware of that

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#the-readonlyarray-type Apparently `readonly PostInterface[]` is syntactic sugar for `ReadonlyArray<PostInterface>`